# Correct understanding and use and of the words in 全都是用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜做的。

Tags: grammar, meaning

In the sentence
全都是用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜做的。

全都是 is a adverb to say without exception.
用 is a preposition to say "with"
爷爷的番茄 , is the object
生菜和黄瓜做 ,is the other part of the object
and 做的 , is the verb , with 的 at the end to meaning a kind of "made of”
Am i right? Im little confused cause 是 and 用 can be also verbs , but that wouldnt make sense with 做 at the end of the sentences and serving as the verb.

Comment: `(这些菜)全都是用爷爷(种)的番茄、生菜和黄瓜做的。 ` ---- all of (the dishes) are made with 番茄、生菜和黄瓜 (raised by) grandpa

Comment: （`，` should be `、`）

Comment: ([这些菜]) ((全都)是) (((用)((爷爷[种]的)(番茄、生菜和黄瓜))) (做的))。

Answer (score 1):

> 全都是用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜做的。

Here **爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜** is a whole part, replace it with **xxx** and we get:

> 全都是用xxx做的

All(全都) are(是) made(做) with(用) xxx.

So the whole sentence be:

All are made with grandpa's tomatoes,lettuce and cucumbers.

The comma "，" might be what confuses you, technically it's incorrect and should be "、", but the misuse is common even among local speakers.

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence, it is used the **Subject+是⋯的** structure. Between 是 and 的 you can use nouns, verbs, adjectives, or little phrases, with different meanings.

主+**是**+名+**的**。
主+**是**+动+**的**。
主+**是**+形+**的**。
主+**是**+小句+**的**。

In the sentence given, between 是 and 的 we have the **verbal phrase** 用爷爷的番茄、生菜和黄瓜做 (as imkzh and Jason Swift correctly said, grammar rules would have "、" instead of "，") made of the prepositional phrase 用爷爷的番茄、生菜和黄瓜 and the verb 做 (thank you @dan for pointing this out).

The verb (verbal phrase in our case) in the structure **主+是+动+的** describes or classifies the subject (主).

**Edit about the 主+是⋯的 structure**
(From the book《现代汉语八百词》. The following list is not complete. It does not include other uses of the structure, including the one for emphasis, each with its own peculiar features.)

[image]

**Can it be a 主(S) + 谓(V) + 宾(O) structure?**

It is not correct to consider 是 as the predicate and 用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜做的 as the object. That way, we would ignore the very existence of the 是⋯的 structure. As explained in the same book cited above, a 的 phrase ('的'字短语) preceded by 是 **forms the 是⋯的 structure** functioning as predicate.

[image]

Comment: It's not 是... 的 structure here. It's 主谓宾 structure. 是 is the verb. The object(宾语) is 的字短语(的 phrase). 的字短语 acts as a noun. To prove it, we can add a noun at the end of the 的字短语, such as 用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜做的"***东西***".

Comment: Hi @dan , please see in my edit the explanation of the 主+是+小句+的 structure. As you can see, what you say about adding a noun after 的 is exactly how the 主+是+小句+的 structure often works.

Comment: Ok, in this case, you can probably understand it that way. In fact, 的字短语 has a larger scope, not particular with 是. E.g. "说话的"出去; 警察处罚"违章的". In OP's case, I prefer analyze it as a generic usage of  的字短语, not 是 ... 的 structure because 是...的 structure is often used for emphatic purpose. By the way, I'm unable to see your picture due to my internet access.

Comment: @dan I posted the picture on my website at the following link https://wearyourchinesename.com/dan.jpg Can you see it this way? I wish it can help.

Comment: Yeah, I can see it now. It's probably a easier way to understand the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> 全都是用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜做的。

First, the sentence is an ***elliptical sentence***. For analysis, we can add a subject 这些. It's basically a ***主(S) + 谓(V) + 宾(O) structure***.

So:

Subject(主语): 这些

Predicate(谓语): 是

Object(宾语): 用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜做的

Adverbal(状语): 全都 (modifying the verb 是)

It's worth to mention that 用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜做的 as a whole is "的字短语"(的 phrase), which works as a ***noun***. To prove this, we can add a noun word at the end like 用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜做的***东西***. In this 的 phrase, 用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜(with grandpa's tomato, lettuce and cucumber) is an ***prepositional phrase*** modifying the verb 做.

For translation, it could be:

> (These) are all made by using grandpa's tomato, lettuce and cucumber.

To understand the structure clearly, we can create a simple sentence with the same structure for comparison here. E.g.

> 这书是用纸做的.

Comment: Hi @dan, I added in my answer one more piece of grammar explaining why it cannot be considered as a 主(S) + 谓(V) + 宾(O) structure. Wishing it can help, you can see the picture also at the following link wearyourchinesename.com/dan2.jpg

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi I see it. Some grammar books take 谓语(predicate) as the combination of verb + object(宾语). The book you read is one of them I think.

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi I looked up <现代汉语> by 高等教育出版社. It says there are two types of analysis for a sentence, namely 层次分析法 and 成分分析法. For 层次分析法, it takes everything except for 主语 as 谓语. For 成分分析法, it takes 中心词(动词) as 谓语. So, you can use either way to parse a sentence.

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi Also, do you see your book talk about the difference between 是字句 and 是...的structure? If not, you can Baidu their differences. I know one way to distinct them is that by removing 是 and 的 to see if the essential meaning changed. If not, it's 是...的 structure. If yes, then it's a 是字句. In OP's example, if we remove 是 and 的, "全都用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜做", the meaning has changed. So it's supposed to be a 是字句.

Comment: Hi, you have to admit that the idea of transforming the 是⋯的 structure into 谓/动(V)+宾(O) (especially the misplaced concept of object here) was not originated by the book <现代汉语>. The 是⋯的 structure is an estabilished rule in Chinese grammar. It is not only used for emphasis. Anyway, your understanding of the sentence, seeing your translation and example, is 100% correct. And, yes, about the book I cited, it clearly says that a 的 phrase preceded by 是 forms the 是⋯的 structure. No verb or object whatsoever. It seems you really don't like this structure!

Comment: Sorry, we wrote at the same time. Yes, it does, quite thoroughly. But, sorry again, I'll continue later. Duty calls.

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi Actually, I'm not quite against 是...的structure. I just looked into the pics you posted again. I think OP's sentence falls into 主+是+动+的, not 主+是+小句+的 because 用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜做 is not 小句. 用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜做 is a phrase where the central verb is 做，用爷爷的番茄，生菜和黄瓜 is a prepositional phrase modifying 做.

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi I think you have nothing wrong here. We just used different ways to analyze the sentence.

Comment: 动 instead of 小句? You're right, I edited my answer, thank you. Difference between 是字句 and 是...的 structure: the book lists the 是...的 structure as one of the 是字句. Removing 是 and 的: the meaning remains often the same when the 是...的 structure is used for emphasis (and in that case no noun can be added after 的). If the meaning changes, it normally means that the 是...的 structure is not used for emphasis.

Answer (score -1):

全都是 用爷爷的 番茄，生菜和黄瓜 做的。

All are (全都是) made (做的) using grandpa's (用爷爷的) tomatoes, vegetables, and cucumbers (番茄，生菜和黄瓜).

Note the difference between Chinese and English in structuring a sentence.